# Validating then using virtual attributes to create a devise user

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, devise

So I have two models, User and Employee. User has one employee and Employee belongs to User. I want to create an employee but first I have to create a new User. My Employee model does not have the attributes `:email, :password, :password_confirmation` so I created virtual attributes. This is the error that pops up `Validation failed: Email is invalid, Password confirmation doesn't match Password`

here is my employee model

```
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user

attr_accessor :email, :password, :password_confirmation
validates :email, format: { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i, on: :create }
validates :password, confirmation: true
end
```

my employee controller

```
class EmployeesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @newuser=User.create!(
      email: :email,
      password: :password,
      password_confirmation: :password_confirmation
    )

    @employee = Employee.new(employee_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @employee.save
        format.html { redirect_to @employee, notice: 'Employee was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @employee }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @employee.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

private
  def employee_params
    params.require(:employee).permit(:name, :contact_no, :role_id, @newuser.id)
  end
end
```

And my form

```html
<%= form_for(employee) do |f| %>
  <% if employee.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(employee.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this employee from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% employee.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :email %>
  </div>
  
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  </div>
  
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :contact_no %>
    <%= f.text_field :contact_no %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :role_id %>
    <%= f.number_field :role_id %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I'm still learning rails and would greatly appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem, it seems that my user parameters weren't following rails' strong parameters rule. so my controller has this now

```
def employee_params
  params.require(:employee).permit(:name, :contact_no, :role_id)
end

def user_params
  params.require(:employee).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)      
end
```

I was then able to make the user using the parameters without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have attributes :email, :password, :password_confirmation then remove the following validation:

```
validates :email, format: { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i, on: :create }
validates :password, confirmation: true
```

from Employee Model.

Comment: I did this but then this error is thrown `Validation failed: Email is invalid, Password confirmation doesn't match Password`

Comment: Have you removed validation from employee model and restart server

Comment: Yes, deleted the validations and restarted server. But it says the validation failed. I dont know how it fails when there is no validation being done in the employee model